# Hadoop Oozie MapReduce Action Custom Partitioner

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, oozie, partitioner, oozie-workflow

How to configure a custom partitioner on oozie workflow XML for a MapReduce Action? I tried using:

```
<property>
    <name>mapreduce.job.partitioner.class</name>
    <value>com.package.MyPartitioner</value>
</property>
<property>
    <name>mapreduce.partitioner.class</name>
    <value>com.package.MyPartitioner</value>
</property>
```

Answer (score 0):

The below is the configuration for specifying partitioner class for mapreduce new api.

```
<property>
   <name>mapreduce.partitioner.class</name>
   <value>test.hadoop.apps.log.LogPartitioner</value>
</property>
```